# CMD: Store the path of a file into a variable, using only the filename

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd, path, directory

I am creating a program that allows the user to 'search' the computer for a file, and if the file `exists`, it will create a shortcut to `start` that file in a new directory. Any and all extensions can be used. The problem is, in order to `start` certain extensions (like .jar), I need the `path` of the file.

None of the examples I've seen so far have been successful in helping me with this, as they usually require an already given path to split.

Ex.

```
(dir %Filename%.%extension% /b /s /a:-D)
```

How would I be able to store *only* the `path` given by this into a variable?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a `for` loop to process the output of a `dir` command, batch will know the path and the filename automatically. From there, it's simply a matter of using the well-known `%~dp` syntax to get the path.

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /s /a:-d') do echo %~dpA
```

where `d` gets the drive and `p` gets the path.

Other options (from `for /?`):

```
%~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
%~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
%~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
%~pI        - expands %I to a path only
%~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
%~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
%~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
%~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
%~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
%~zI        - expands %I to size of file
```